# How to modify the height on the text

Tags: css, sass, letter-spacing

I want to reduce the height of a text, How can i do?

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: <div class="column" span="row">
            <h1 class="about-me__first-title">Nistor Andrei Marian</h1>
          </div>     and scss    .about-me__first-title{
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 64px;

Comment: Hey AndreiN, I just posted an answer, you simply can use "line-height" property on your h1 tags. Let me know if that helps cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
    span {
      line-height:2.5
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <span>Mistor</span>
    <br>
    <span>Gathus</span>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/OJXJJxd

Comment: Yea,it's work with line-height, in the project line-height it was so high

Comment: OK glad I could help! Feel free to mark the answer as the accepted one if it helped. Have a nice day